# C++ Safely and Efficiently Casting std::weak_ordering to int

Tags: c++, casting, compare, c++20

C++20 is introducing a new comparison type: [std::weak_ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/weak_ordering).

It allows for representing less than, equal to, or greater than.

However, some older functions use an `int` for a similar purpose. Such as [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), which uses the signature

```
int compar (const void* p1, const void* p2);
```

How can I cast `std::weak_ordering` to `int` for the use in a function such as `qsort`?

Here is an example situation:

```
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long a = 2354, b = 1234;
    std::weak_ordering cmp = a <=> b;
    
    if (cmp > 0)  std::cout << "a is greater than b" << std::endl;
    if (cmp == 0) std::cout << "a is equal to b" << std::endl;
    if (cmp < 0)  std::cout << "a is less than b" << std::endl;

    int equivalent_cmp = cmp; // errors
}
```

---

In testing, I noticed that using a `reinterpret_cast` to `int8_t` type does work, but I am not sure if this would be portable.

```
int equivalent_cmp = *(int8_t *)&cmp;
```

or equivalently,

```
int equivalent_cmp = *reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(&cmp);
```

Is this safe?

Furthermore, there are some other solutions that can work, but are inefficient compared this "unsafe" method. All of these would be slower than the above solutions

```
    int equivalent_cmp = (a > b) - (a < b);
```

or

```
    int equivalent_cmp;
    if (cmp < 0)       equivalent_cmp = -1;
    else if (cmp == 0) equivalent_cmp =  0;
    else               equivalent_cmp =  1;
```

Is there a better solution that would be guaranteed to work?

Comment: This is C++. Why are you using `qsort()` instead of `std::sort`?

Comment: For the example of a function that uses an int as a compare type. It's only an example.

Comment: "*forcing a cast*" That's not forcing a cast.

Comment: What I mean is that C++, especially newer versions, have different expectations than old C functions like `qsort()` so the differences in C++ are largely academic, if not irrelevant.

Comment: @NicolBolas Point taken. Edits made. I presume that kind of cast is called a reinterpretation cast. Though I am not confident to be honest.

Comment: "_using a reinterpret_cast to int8_t type does work_" - just because a cast *compiles* doesn't mean it **works**, i.e. has reliable, defined behaviour. many casts will compile but give your program undefined behaviour. this specific one might work in a defined way if int8_t is a char type, via aliasing allowances for char* pointers, but even if you weren't casting to a char type it'd still compile but confer undefined behaviour. so you should generally use other ways, such as bit_cast. but in this case Jeff's is superior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a better solution that would be guaranteed to work?

No.

The standard does not specify the contents or representation of the ordering classes. Barry's answer is based on reasonable assumptions, that are likely to hold, but they are not guaranteed.

Should you need it, your best bet is to write something like your last snippet

```
constexpr int ordering_as_int(std::weak_ordering cmp) noexcept {
    return (cmp < 0) ? -1 : ((cmp == 0) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can I cast `std::weak_ordering` to `int` for the use in a function such as `qsort`?

The easy answer is: don't use `qsort`, use `std::sort`, it'll perform better anyway.

---

That said, we know that `std::weak_ordering` has to have some integral type member, and C++20 does come with a mechanism to pull it out: [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast):

```cpp
static_assert(std::bit_cast<int8_t>(0 <=> 1) == -1);
```

The rule is that the type you're casting to (in this case `int8_t`) has to be the same size as the type you're casting from (in this case `std::strong_ordering`). That's a constraint on `bit_cast`, so it's safe - if the implementation actually stores an `int` instead of an `int8_t`, this won't compile.

So more generally, you'd have to write a short metaprogram to determine the correct signed integer type to cast into.

---

Note that while `weak_ordering` and `strong_ordering` will just be implemented as storing an integer (though not `int` as illustrated in the standard), `partial_ordering` will probably *not* be implemented as storing an `int` and a  `bool` - it will likely still be implemented as a single integer. So this trick won't work.

Comment: "you'd have to write a short metaprogram". Would you mind elaborating? How would one decide the correct type at compile time?

Comment: And I agree `std::sort` would be better than `qsort`. It was just an example.

Comment: Except both gcc and VC++ use a common enum type for all three implementations, where `less==-1`, `equal==0` and `greater==1`.  Frankly, it's silly that these aren't just defined as enums!

Comment: @Spencer You can't make two enums that are convertible to each other (or in this case, having `strong_ordering` convertible to `weak_ordering` convertible to `partial_ordering`).

Comment: @Barry Is there a need for implicit conversion like that?  Otherwise a `static_cast` (or a function that wraps one) would suffice.

Comment: @Spencer Yeah there's definitely code that wants a `weak_ordering` that should happily take a `strong_ordering`.

Comment: @Barry Ah well, I thought it was a holdover from the old pre-`enum class` technique of making "custom enums".

Answer (score 1):

I needed this conversion recently and came up with this solution, which will use bit_cast if possible and otherwise will fall back to slower method.

```
template<typename T>
concept Sane_ordering =
    std::bit_cast<signed char>(T::equivalent) == 0 &&
    std::bit_cast<signed char>(T::less) < 0 &&
    std::bit_cast<signed char>(T::greater) > 0;

template<Sane_ordering T>
inline constexpr int to_int_helper(T ordering) {
    return std::bit_cast<signed char>(ordering);
}

template<typename T>
inline constexpr int to_int_helper(T ordering) {
    return (ordering > 0) - (ordering < 0);
}

inline constexpr int to_int(std::weak_ordering ordering) {
    return to_int_helper(ordering);
}
```